# Under what circumstances is $MYVIMRC not set?

Tags: windows, vim

I am working with a gvim installation on windows (version 7.3). After starting up, I expected the variable `$MYVIMRC` to be set, yet it is not. Is there a reaseon why it is not set.

There *is* a vimrc file since many setting are different from the default settings.

I checked the for the value of `MYVIMRC` with

```
:echo ">" . $MYVIMRC . "<"
```

The gvim executable is located in *c:\workarea\Vim\vim73*, the *_vimrc* (that is being read on gvim's start) in *c:\workare\Vim*. After I have started gvim, I can edit the _vimrc file with a

```
:e $VIM/_vimrc
```

With `:version` I found that the *system vimrc file* is under `$VIM/vimrc`. This file doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you check, with `:echo $MYVIMRC`?!

Comment: Where is the system vimrc file?  Look about half-way down the optput of `:version`.

Comment: @benjifisher The system vimrc file is under $VIM/vimrc. This file didn't exist. With such a $VIM/vimrc file the $MYVIMRC variable now correctly(?) points to $VIM/_vimrc.

Comment: So, problem solved?  I do not think it is supposed to happen, but maybe vim decided that `$VIM/_vimrc` was the system vimrc file instead of the personal one.

Comment: Yes, for me the problem is solved. You (benjifisher) have given me the right hint. If you made your hint an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote,

> There is a vimrc file since many setting are different from the default settings.

That could be because there is a system vimrc file.  Look about half-way down the output of `:version` to see where vim looks for the system vimrc file.  There are also some less common ways of changing settings.  See `:help startup`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running `:echo $MYVIMRC` and `$MYVIMRC` is not defined I bet it is because there is not a ~/.vimrc file (or $HOME/_vimrc on windows).

From `:help $MYVIMRC`

> Four places are searched for initializations. The first that exists is
>   used, the others are ignored.  The $MYVIMRC environment variable is
>   set to the file that was first found

(Second place of that four places is the users vimrc.)

((Just check `:help $MYVIMRC` for more info))

If there are settings different from the default ones you can check other variables to find where that settings are changed:

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
:echo $MYGVIMRC
:echo $VIM
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

You can check:

```
:help startup
:help gui-fork
```

to see how this works.

You can use as well the `verbose` command to see where some settings are defined. For example if you know  is mapped:

```
:verbose map <F5>
```

Will return something like:

> * :python debugger.run()
>
> ```
> Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vdebug/plugin/vdebug.vim
> ```

(That is from my particular vim configuration)